# string index out of bound error name_tools

Tags: python, csv

I have a python script behaving weirdly:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
import csv
import sys
import name_tools as nt
f = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
try:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        row = [author.strip() for author in row]
        print row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], len(row)
        if row[1] and row[2]:
            print len(row),  row[0], len(row), nt.match(row[1], row[2])
finally:
    f.close()
```

The input file looks like:

```
" ROW_NUMBER "," AUTHOR_3PCATALOG "," AUTHOR_AMAZON "," LABEL "
" 1 ","  "," Tavoillot, Pierre-Henri "," NEGATIVE "
" 2 ","  "," di Bonaventura, Allegra "," NEGATIVE "
" 3 "," Stephen Jones "," Jones, Stephen "," NEGATIVE "
" 4 ","  "," Weisenberger, Dr. Gary J. "," NEGATIVE "
" 5 "," Cassandra Austin "," Irwin "," NEGATIVE "
" 6 ","  "," Cain, Paul "," NEGATIVE "
" 473 "," Craig  Harline ","  William Craig     "," NEGATIVE "
```

Somehow the record with row number 473 create the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./author_preprocessing.py", line 14, in <module>
    print len(row),  row[0], len(row), nt.match(row[1], row[2])
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/name_tools/match.py", line 102, in match
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/name_tools/match.py", line 19, in middle_initials
IndexError: string index out of range
```

The output of the program is:

```
ROW_NUMBER AUTHOR_3PCATALOG AUTHOR_AMAZON LABEL 4
4 ROW_NUMBER 4 0.0
1  Tavoillot, Pierre-Henri NEGATIVE 4
2  di Bonaventura, Allegra NEGATIVE 4
3 Stephen Jones Jones, Stephen NEGATIVE 4
4 3 4 0.98
4  Weisenberger, Dr. Gary J. NEGATIVE 4
5 Cassandra Austin Irwin NEGATIVE 4
4 5 4 0.0
6  Cain, Paul NEGATIVE 4
473 Craig  Harline William Craig NEGATIVE 4
4 473 4
```

Comment: @AmanDeepGuatam Apparently you are failing on a record, which is shorter, than you expect. It is very likely, it is not the record "473", but the next one.

Comment: @all those who have downvoted, please see the answer. I still believe it was a genuine question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name_tools` seems to split the string arguments passed internally and does not handle is more than one white space is between characters. So in the particular case `Craig  Harline` has two spaces in between `Craig` and `Harline`. a `split()` and `join()` did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

## Assert length of your `row`

Following line in your code should give you the answer.

```
assert len(row)
```

If you want to get a bit more descriptive error trace, use this:

```
msg = "row must have 4 elements and has {rowlen}. row: {row}"
assert len(row) == 4, msg.format(rowlen=len(row), row=row)
```

This assert shall be inside of your loop and before you attempt to access items from the row.

Comment: Thanks Jan. but this is not the issue. I figured it out.